# How to run roscore or roslaunch when i boot

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ros Kinetic version.

How to run roscore or roslaunch automatically when i boot .

i tried add script /etc/init.d and /etc/rc.local , but they didn't work.

How can i do ?

---

Edit: Thank you for your answer.

I follow your advise using systemd.

but i have some error with this method like this.

```
 5월 08 17:56:00 Jo startup.sh[3794]: lcd: cannot connect to X server
 5월 08 17:56:00 Jo startup.sh[3794]: [lcd-2] process has died [pid 3868, exit code 1, cmd /home/jo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lcd/lcd __name:=lcd __log:=/root/.ros/log/a1512d42-529d-11e8-a4c9-00012957ec7a/lcd-2.log].
 5월 08 17:56:00 Jo startup.sh[3794]: log file: /root/.ros/log/a1512d42-529d-11e8-a4c9-00012957ec7a/lcd-2*.log
 5월 08 18:03:39 Jo systemd[1]: Started start roslaunch.
```

what can i do  ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290599/how-to-run-roscore-or-roslaunch-when-i-boot/) by [jo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35012/jo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem using [robot_upstart_pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart).

But they didn't work UI program. Only normal node.

Thanks for your answer !

Ah. [robot_upstart_pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) is create service file automatic as a BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi's answer.

---

Originally posted by [jo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35012/jo/) with karma: 46 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaorusha](https://answers.ros.org/users/92748/kaorusha/) on 2022-01-06**:
For nodes running on multiple machine, `robot_upstart` is easier then manually write `systemd` to set the `ROS_MASTER_URI`, just remember to add the --master option.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the steps:

1. Make a new script file lets take `startup.sh`.
2. Before calling the roscore and roslaunch in startup file, the ros environment should be sourced, so source the environment by addiing
   `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.sh`  or  `. /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.sh`
3. Now you can add the ros command in the startup file like `roscore` or `roslaunch`.
   if directly roscore or rolaunch does not work launch this command from the ros/bin by adding the line  `/opt/ros/<distro>/bin/roscore`.
4. Give executable permission to file `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/startup.sh`

Note: make sure while creating the new file you add  `#!/bin/sh` in the first line.

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35012/jo/) on 2018-05-08**:
Thanks for your answer.

Here add my ~~.sh

#!/bin/bash
cd $home

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
roslaunch ros_tutorials_topic union.launch

exit 0

but it didn't work at boot.
It's cannot even do.

my .sh file root is /home/username
and my pkg root is /home/username/catkin_ws/src/

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-08**:
I have written a simple script, you can modify it according to your requirement.

````
#!/bin/sh
filename="/home/username/boot_log"_$current_time.txt
echo "logging started" >> $filename
. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh  
roscore >> $filename
sleep 1
#/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore 2>&1 >> $filename & ```

**Comment by [jo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35012/jo/) on 2018-05-08**:\
Thanks. using init.d , It has very many errors in my pc. so i used systemd method. Thanks for your interest and help. :)
````

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using systemd . Here are the few links that helped me

1. [create a systemd service](https://datasciencenovice.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/spark-stand-alone-cluster-as-a-systemd-service-ubuntu-16-04centos-7/)
2. I am trying to launch lidar on boot, hence i also need some port permission/or available sequence  and [here is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463755/linux-start-daemon-on-connected-usb-serial-dongle) that might help

Here is how my both service and .sh file look like

Service

```
[Unit]
Description=start roscore
After=remote-fs.target
After=syslog.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rosCoreService.sh
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/bc/.bashrc
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/bc/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch multitower_rplidar rplidar.launch
```

some of them might not be needed but i don't know which of them are.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5